# Abnormal behavior of RealDigits[x]

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, documentation, machine-precision, arbitrary-precision

In the **Details** of the document of [`RealDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealDigits.html) writes the following line:

> `RealDigits[x]` *normally* returns a list of digits of length `Round[Precision[x]]`.

Then when will `RealDigits[x]` *abnormally* return something and what will be returned?

The **details** has shown us one of them:

> `RealDigits[0.]` gives `{{0},-Floor[Accuracy[0.]]}`.

Are there more?

The following is one I found today:

```
x = 1.2``2;
Round@Precision@x
(* 2 *)
Length@First@RealDigits@x
(* 3 *)
```

Is there a complete summary for the behaviors of `RealDigits` with only one valid argument? Does these abnormalities follow any unified rule?

Answer (score 4):

```
test[x_] := 
 With[{a = Length[First@RealDigits[x]], b = Round[Precision[x]]},
  a == b
  ]
```

the test is `False` for any Integer and Rational, exact symbols like  Pi, etc.

Its also `False` for `N[m, n]` for any `m` power of 10 and `n` been an Integer.  As well as for some other Real numbers, I'm guessing depending on the internal representation.

```
test[N[1, 10.3]]
```

> ```
> False
> ```