# RealDigits and functional style

Tags: functions, functional-style, number-representation, guidelines

So while thinking about [Replacing numbers of which you only know certain digits](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108112/5478) I have faced, again, a problem that I find hard to extract from `RealDigits'` output something I want, what should be natural to do based on docs:

> gives a list of the digits in the approximate real number x, together with the number of digits that are to the left of the decimal point.

Nice explanation till the point that for e.g. `0.01` you will get negative number of digits that are to the left... Which probably mean that `Abs` of that that is number of `0`s inserted just on the right side.

**The broad question** is:

- maybe I'm expecting from `RealDigits` to much, then I would like to have better intuition with working with it. So I need better definition than the one from docs.

In case when that's unclear/too broad, here's **the short question**:

- Basing on the definition above, it should be easy, or at least there should be a neat functional way to extract from the real number, digits that are on the left and right side of the decimal point.

For **example**:

```
1.019 ==> {{1}, {0,1,9, 0, 0, ....}}   (*or*)   {{1}, {0, 1, 8, 9, 9, 9, ....}
(*since the latter is the representation of my input dictated by 
  binary system with finite precision*)
```

**My approach**

So, in linked topic I've done something what (almost) works but is ugly considering want to do something basic with built in function's result.

```
 f = TakeDrop[
     If[Negative[#2], ArrayPad[#1, {Abs[#2], 0}], #1], 
     Clip[#2, {0, \[Infinity]}]
 ] & @@ RealDigits[#] &

 f /@ {1.01, 1.019}
```

> ```
> {
>    {{1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}},
>    {{1}, {0, 1, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}}
>   }
> ```

IMO, this should be possible to do with less effort. How?

Comment: If the default format bothers you, you could maybe consider applying `RealDigits[]` on the `FractionalPart[]` of your number, and `IntegerDigits[]` to the `IntegerPart[]`.

Comment: @J.M. `RealDigits@FractionalPart[1.019]` still has negative second part. So `ArrayPad` is inevitable.

Comment: @J.M. Maybe I should rather ask, what is the form of `RealDigits'` output useful for? It was never for me, I always had to built something ugly on that.

Comment: Yes, but that is now because the fractional part is a number in $(0,1)$, so the second part of the output is a nonpositive integer.

Comment: @J.M. that statement isn't in documentation and I'm expecting "the number of digits that are to the left of the decimal point.". So I don't claim you are not right.

Comment: @J.M. I have a problem because I'm not an expert and I don't know if 1. I missing something 2. Documentations is bad, 3. I can't read with understanding.

Comment: You might consider, as another example, the output of `RealDigits[1.234*^-5, 10, Automatic, -1]`.But, going back to the basic use of `RealDigits[]`: I suppose the phrasing of the docs could be better, but I had always interpreted the output of `RealDigits[]` this way: `x == FromDigits[#1] b^(#2 - Length[#1]) & @@ RealDigits[x, b]` where `b` is by default 10.

Comment: @J.M. I'd rather say, the documentation is wrong and misleading because it  skipped the definition of " -5 digits to the left of the decimal point".

Comment: I guess this question is somewhat related?: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98711/1871

Comment: Somewhat related perhaps?: [(82605)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/82605/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, thanks for the link. I don't know if this question can be answered well. Basically the intuition build by reading docs for `RealDigits` fails with simple examples like `.019` then `RealDigits[.019, 10, 10, -1]` works well but is not general enough to take care about `1.019`.